# Submitting the user profile edit form is logging me out

Tags: users

I have a strange issue. I am using Drupal 6. When I am submitting my profile form, it is logging me out.

When I check my database `users` table, the password field is having null value.

I don't know where to check this issue, to solve it.

Comment: Post your server's error log from the moment of failure. And RDBMS error log too, if possible. Without that, there's no way to help you.

Comment: md5() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /mySite/modules/user/user.module on line 240

Comment: I didn't find any error logs related to the above bug except the above one. When I saved the form, it is logging me out.

Comment: Well, that explains why password hash is null - md5 can't work on a non-string. It seems to happen when you have conflicting modules: https://drupal.org/node/426416